# Wordpress: You do not have sufficient permissions to install plugins on this site

Tags: wordpress

for an unknown reason so far, my wordpress website shows, whichever page i try to access:

You do not have sufficient permissions to install plugins on this site.

i might fall into a specific wp bug related to unstable release, i'm on "WordPress 4.8-alpha-40040"

i'm not logged in, and the problem occurs whether i'm accessing the root of the website or the admin url.

user rights seem ok (i checked usermeta prefixes).

i tried setting wp_debug to true, the message still shows unvariably..

[screenshot from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVxjy.png)

thank you for your help!

jerome

Comment: You are not an `administrator`. You do not have the previledge to install the plugins.

Comment: actually i wasn't trying anything special, just access admin or index of the site, without being logged in.
i was pointed to the solution in the wordpress beta forum : one pluging was doing something that caused the error, disabling it solved my problem. thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the directory permissions for plugin directory

Comment: thank you for your help, i solved my problem. (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One plugin was doing something (probably related to installing another plugin) that caused the error, disabling it solved my problem.